# Split strings and store in array

Tags: php

I have a variable called : **$elementname**

The print values using :

**print_r($elementname) is :**

```
hardwareaccessIPsdefaultgwinterface_nameinterface_rxinterface_txinterface_error
```

**While, var_dump($elementname) is :**

```
string(8) "hardware"
string(6) "access"
string(3) "IPs"
string(9) "defaultgw"
string(14) "interface_name"
string(12) "interface_rx"
string(12) "interface_tx"
string(15) "interface_error"
```

My question is how may i split this strings and store in an array ?

From the print_r, it looks joined with no **delimiter** :(
There must be a way since **var_dump** was able to split it in the output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$elementname` has some kind of delimiter and `print_r` just stripping it. Use `var_dump($elementname)` to show us what really going on there.

Comment: @OrelEraki i thought i provided var_dump output already ?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It's seems that the only time it will print it in this kind of fashion is because `$elementname` is an array. try echoing $elementname[0] and see if it gives you `hardware` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has whitespace character that is not visible to us. try this 
myarray will have the splitted data like you wanted

```
$myarray = preg_split("[\s]",$elementname)
```